# Why do C programs return an int?

Tags: c

I usually get a warning from the compiler if I tell it to return anything else.

Comment: Do you mean, "Why is the signature of *main* the way it is?" (Please remember to take time and qualify questions.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the exit code provided to whoever called your program. Non-zero value usually signifies error.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: because that's what the C standard says:

#### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

> 1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. **It shall be defined with a return type of `int`** and with no
>   parameters: 
>   `int main(void) { /* ... */ }` 
>   or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>   `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
>   or equivalent;<sup>9)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner. (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

The C standard demands it because there's no mechanism to communicate to the environment that you'll be returning something else than an integral value. Therefore, `int` is the only possible type; it covers all platforms and the expected numeric ranges they expect the process to return to them.